# What missions provide the best RP in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm level 49 trying to level up so I can access better missions and rewards (like the tank).  I mostly play solo and occasionally with 1-4 friends.

What are some good missions to do as a group to get RP?  Who should I call for missions with best RP payout?

Comment: I am almost positive that races net the most RP currently, assuming you consistently place well.

Comment: Survival is great in groups, and can get you a lot of RP, assuming you do well enough ;)  The one I've been playing regularly has been giving 3400 RP and $20,000 for completion.

Comment: Air Races also make good RP & $

Comment: @turbo is there a specific race I should join from Pause>Online>Jobs or should i just use the Quick race feature on the phone?

Comment: Basically any race, although you can do more of the shorter ones quickly.  You can try Down the Drain and Criminal records, although you'll usually find people trading wins or doing the 7k RP glitch on these races.

Comment: The problem I encountered with races was players circling the wrong way, people changing lap #s to 99 etc. If you're playing with friends, by all means, but with randoms you need to pay close attention. Last time I tried to do any races, it was pretty hard to find one that wasn't the usual 3 lap Criminal Records on motorcycles.

Comment: It looks to me like Point to point races give the most RP.  In a 2 person point-to-point race, coming in 1st nets you 1950 RP and second place gives 1345 RP.  They take around 2-3 minutes and are more fun than a quick lap race (less loading between races)

Comment: @nosf yes, that's probably people doing the 7k RP glitch.  FistOfFury, do you mean the quick action menu races? I don't see how a point to point race would have less loading time than a lap race.

Comment: @turbo I don't mean the race loads fast, i mean it's more RP per race.  Therefore you get more RP per load.

Comment: I don't think anyone has mentioned that you get 2200 RP for a nice relaxing game of golf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long paste, thanks to GTAForums iirc - as of 1.04

If you want to grind, have someone host the job 'Coveted' under missions - 950 RP, $12k payout and is fairly fast once you have it down. As it isn't given by any character, you can Replay it from the post mission menu.

Mission Name / Cash / Rank req. / RP gained - all values on hardmode, solo.

Gerald
Trevor's Enigma: 3,500 - 7 - 4,000
Dish the Dirt (1-4): 3,500 - 45 - 2,510
War and Pieces (1-4): 3,500 - 30 - 2,160
Meth'd Up (1-4): 2,500 - 7 - 1,100
No Hay Bronca (1-4): 2,500 - 9 - 1,320
Violent Duct (1-4): 1,500 - 15 - 1,140
Flood in the LS River (1-4): 1,500 - 6 - 1,400
Death Metal (1-4): 1,000 - 6 - 1,320
Chumash and Grab (2-4): 1,000 - 35 - 1,900
Gassed Up (1-4): 1,000 - 12 - 1,050
Pier Pressure (1-4): 750 - 6 - 1,000
Deal Breaker (1-4): 500 - 6 - 1,340

Simeon
Blow Up III (1-2): 1,500 - 31 - 1,280
Blow Up II (1-2): 1,500 - 20 - 1,260
Rich Men in Richman (1-4): 1,000 - 5 - 1,100
ATV Steal (1-4): 1,000 - 25 - 1,020
El Burro Heists (1-4): 1,000 - 10 - 1,170
Gentry Does It (1-4): 1,000 - 10 - 1,100
All in the Game (1-2): 1,000 - 10 - 1,060
It Takes a Thief (1-4): 1,000 - 5 - 1,460
Blow Up (1-2): 750 - 12 - 1,650
Rockford Roll (1-2): 750 - 5 - 1,050
Chasers II (1-2): 500 - 16 - 1,060
Chasers (1-2): 500 - 5 - 1,220
Where Credit's Due (1-2): 500 - 5 - 1,050

Lamar
Going Down the GOH: 2,500 - 20 - 1,340
No Smoking (1-4): 2,500 - 30 - 1,680
Caught Napping: 2,500 - 20 - 1,450
Lost MC RIP (1-2): 2,500 - 25 - 1,370
San Andreas Seoul: 1,500 - 16 - 1,200
Ticket to Elysium (1-4): 1,500 - 18 - 1,610
Ballas to the Wall (1-2): 500 - 5 - 1,200

Martin
Rooftop Rumble (1-4): 12,500 - 75 - 4,350
Defender (1-2): 11,500 - 70 - 3,600
Trash Talk (1-6): 10,000 - 81 - 3,050
Extradition (1-6): 10,000 - 50 - 2,350
Judging the Jury (1-8): 10,000 - 65 - 3,560
Mixed up with Coke (1-6): 9,000 - 45 - 3,350
Dry Docking (1-4): 8,000 - 45 - 2,530
The Los Santos Connection (1-6): 8,000 - 40 - 3,900
Stick Up the Stickup Crew (1-4): 6,000 - 40 - 3,750
Show Me the Monet (1-4): 5,000 - 55 - 2,860
Check Out Time (1-2): 5,000 (car is worth 9,000)* - 35 - 1,110
Grab Your Ballas (1-4): 4,500 - 40 - 2,530
Editor and Thief (1-2): 4,500 - 45 - 1,130
Out of Court Settlement (1-2): 4,500 (car is worth 22,000)* - 22 - 1,160
Holed Up - Burton (1-4): 3,500 - 50 - 2,720
Water the Vineyard (1-2): 2,500 - 40 - 1,720
Death From Above (1-4): 2,500 - 24 - 1,500
Cleaning the Cat House (1-4): 1,500 - 45 - 4,090

Lester
Docks to Stock (1-4): 12,500 - 70 - 3,360
Stocks and Scares (1-4): 12,500 - 70 - 4,050
American Exports (1-4): 11,500 - 65 - 3,150
On Maneuvers (1-3): 11,500 - 65 - 2,550
Docks to Stock II (1-4): 10,000 - 75 - 2,850
Chemical Extraction (1-6): 10,000 - 65 - 4,030
Bust Out (1-4): 10,000 - 55 - 1,820
Hack and Dash (1-4): 8,000 - 60 - 1,520
Sinking Feeling (2-4): 7,000 - 55 - 3,000
Quarry Quarry (1-4): 5,000 - 30 - 1,920
Teaser Trailer (1-4): 5,000 - 40 - 2,510
A Titan of a Job (1-6): 5,000 - 24 - 1,000
By Land, Sea, and Air (2-4): 4,500 - 30 - 1,930
Four Trailers (1-6): 3,500 - 45 - 4,000
High Priority Case (1-4): 3,500 - 25 - 1,650
Landing Strip (2-4): 3,500 - 22 - 1,150
Last Chopper Out of LS (2-2): 3,500 - 25 - 1,150
The Parking Garage (2-4): 2,500 - 55 - 4,810
Cop's Capacity (1-2): 2,500 (car is worth 16,000) - 19 - 2,000

Ron
Base Invaders (1-4): 12,500 - 27 - 1,460
Landing Gear (4-6): 11,500 - 55 - 2,800
Wet Work (1-4): 7,000 - 55 - 3,650
Crank Up the Volume (1-4): 5,000 - 30 - 1,200
A Boat in the Bay (1-4): 3,500 - 40 - 1,100
Daemon Run (2-4): 2,500 - 25 - 1,500
Turbine Carbine (1-4): 2,500 - 25 - 1,560
Fuelling the Flames (1-4): 2,500 - 20 - 1,270
Romance isn't Dead (1-4): 1,000 - 13 - 1,150

Trevor
Chopper Tail (1-4): 11,500 - 70 - 3,450
Method in the Madness (2-4): 11,500 - 65 - 4,670
Satellite Communications: 10,000 - 60 - 4,900
Out of Harmony (1-4): 7,000 - 50 - 2,650
Crystal Clear Out (1-4): 5,000 - 28 - 1,820
Diamonds are for Trevor (1-4): 5,000 - 70 - 3,490
Lost My Mind (1-4): 2,500 - 20 - 1,650

Comment: i noticed that sometimes i get half as much RP/money as my friend (level 69) in a given mission.  Is this due to level cap?

Answer (score 2):

Do the Coveted mission.

It gets really boring but you can play some music in the background and it gives $18000 and 1900-2100 RP

Answer (score 1):

when you have a buzzard chopper, crystal clear out 3 is really fast and extremely easy.. and it is available at lv 40  (before buzzard is unlocked) it gives 7000 cash and 2000 rp solo on hard     the other bonus is you can do this over and over again without using any ammo (you will notice the money saved)

with the chopper most of the missions that require killing stuff become blitzable

Answer (score 1):

Rooftop Rumble - opens at rank 75, but by choosing 'quick' option you can join others games. Earns $18,750 + 4k+ rp on hard (1.5x) for a quick and really easy mission!

Tip - sprint down the side of the building, climb on the wall & hedge, crouch, then pick off all the dudes over the top of the wall!

Answer (score 1):

I personaly play Los Santos Connection, and it earns about 22,000-24,000 RP, with all the crate drops and expected kills. I was level 34. Level 80 helps a lot, too. Just use an Armoured Kuruna and destroy the buzzard at the three helipads, at the air port. Go to the end of the runway, destroy the suppliers plane, and drive to Madrazo's house.

Answer (score 0):

Doing Martin's Out of Court Settlement is the easiest since 2 stars is easy to handle, NEVER do Martin's mission Death From Above it is long and almost impossible for every level person

Answer (score 0):

Try these: http://www.gamechup.com/gta-5-online-guide-best-missions-to-farm-money-fast/

Personally I like Coveted,
its extremely fast (I'm lvl 44 myself) once you have it down, plus it is easily done solo with a sniper once you learn all the spawn locations.  Its even faster with a group but since your 45 I'd recomend this one:

by his estimate it pays out 700k an hour

Answer (score 0):

Since I am a low level the best I have found is potshot (or something like that) and on hard it gives $10500 and 1300+ rp

Answer (score 0):

Potshot would be the best mission. give you $10500 and 1300+ rp. The mission can be completed in 3 min. very vast and easy

Answer (score 0):

I personally like crank up the volume the beast I do the mission in about 20 mins and get around 4000 Rp and $20000 I'm lvl 44 and it takes about 2 and a half of the missions to rank up.

Answer (score -2):

Do rooftop rumble on hard it gives you 18,750 money and around 3.800 RP. Best to do it with 3 other crew members.

Comment: and im lel 99 i was lel 40 something before i got help from a crew and now apart of the family... redmonster14.... thats the crew that help me lel up and make money?